# Consulta inversa para obtener los objetos relacionados

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

Tengo un proyecto el cual se trata de manejar diversos aspectos de la vida de las llantas de ciertos vehiculos y hace poco se acaba de incorporar Django Rest para la creacion de API's, y en una de ella se solicito que se entrege el vehiculo y sus llantas.
Sin embargo no e podido realizar dicha accion.
Estos son las partes mas relevantes del modelo.

```
class Llanta(models.Model):
    # Modelo de la Llanta

    numero_economico = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    compania = models.ForeignKey(Compania, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    vehiculo = models.ForeignKey(Vehiculo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    taller = models.ForeignKey(Taller, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    renovador = models.ForeignKey('Renovador', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Vehiculo(models.Model):
    # Modelo del Vehiculo

    numero_economico = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    marca = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    compania = models.ForeignKey(Compania, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ubicacion = models.ForeignKey(Ubicacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    aplicacion = models.ForeignKey(Aplicacion, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_de_llantas = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=8)
```

Y aqui esta la vista del API que utilizo con DDRF:

```
class Ordenamientovehiculollantas(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = OrdenamientoPorvehiculoSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication] 


    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        perfil = models.Perfil.objects.get(user=user)
        compania = perfil.compania
        vehiculo = models.Vehiculo.objects.filter(compania = compania)
        
        return vehiculo

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 

        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Y esta es la respuesta que da:

```
{
  "count": 6720,
  "next": "http://localhost:8000/app/ordenamintoLlantas/?limit=100&offset=100",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "Vehiculovehiculo": "128",
      "numero_economico": "12811",
      "compania": 23,
      "vehiculo": 28547,
      "taller": null,
    }
}
```

Mi intencion es que se agrege otro valor que sea las llantas de ese vehiculo, pero no encontre la manera de agregarlo, intente con una consulta inversa utilizando "llanta_set" pero despues de indagar en la documentacion vi que no era por ahi, o en su defecto no logre realizarlo.

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Adicion: La respuesta que quiero obtener es algo como:

```
{
  "count": 6720,
  "next": "http://localhost:8000/app/ordenamintoLlantas/?limit=100&offset=100",
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "Vehiculovehiculo": "128",
      "numero_economico": "12811",
      "compania": 23,
      "vehiculo": 28547,
      "taller": null,
      "llantas":  [
                {
                 'numero_economico': 1515,
                 'taller' : 'Taller x'
                },
                {
                 'numero_economico': 1515,
                 ''taller' : 'Taller x'
                {
      ]
    }
}
```